# Google Chrome - iframe sandbox to disable hyperlink submission is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

Opening this page in Google Chrome latest stable version using (HTTPS, must have to use HTTPS because of other dependencies) `https://example.com/test.php`

Inside the page, I have this code only (which is a Brother printer maintenance page) :

```
<iframe sandbox="" id="iframe_display_modules" src="https://192.168.1.57/general/information.html?kind=item"></iframe>
```

Now, Google Chrome does not respect the parameter i have used "sandbox". I can use any link from the iframe by clicking on it which should not be allowed right?
[image]

Can anyone advise then how i can block the users to click on that iframe?

Comment: Users only can see, but i want them to unable to submit or i want them not to navigate other links in that iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't something that the `sandbox` attribute does. Its primary purpose is to restrict the capabilities of the child frame to operate on the browser (e.g, preventing it from loading links to the top browser frame, displaying popups, running scripts, *etc*.) It does not restrict what the user can do with the frame.

If you want to prevent the user from interacting with a frame, consider displaying a transparent element on top of the frame to prevent it from receiving click events:

```css
#frame-holder {
  position: relative;
}

#frame-holder iframe {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#frame-holder div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame-holder">
  <div></div>
  <iframe sandbox src="http://example.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```